# Como retornar variable de un EventEmitter de telnet-client

Tags: javascript, nodejs, variables, telnet, retorno

Buenos dias estimados compañeros, hoy le escribo porque necesito de su ayuda para resolver este tema que se me esta presentando y acontinuacion les detallo :

Resulta que necesito hacer una conexion telnet (estoy trabajando con nodejs) a un dispositivo ejecutar un comando y tomar esa respuesta para hacer siguientes operaciones (procesar y guardar) etc. el problema es que he intentado hacerlo de diferentes formas de ejecucion de la documentacion telnet-client y la unica que me ha funcionado es con callbacks, intente probar las promises pero tema esta que ejecuta el cmd antes o en el momento de hacer el login de equipo.

Basicamente lo que necesito es obtener esa respuesta pero esta la obtengo en un eventEmiter de la clase y por lo que he investigado no es posible hacerlo.

Agradecido de antemano por su ayuda

```html
const { Telnet } = require('telnet-client')

const testTelnet = async (host, dns) => {

process.on('unhandledRejection', error => {
    console.log("**TELNET CONNECTION ERROR ***", error);

});

const params = {
    host: host,
    port: 23,
    shellPrompt: '#',
    negotiationMandatory: false,
    loginPrompt: dns + ' login:',
    username: user,
    password: password,
    failedLoginMatch: '/error en autenticacion/',
    timeout: 5000,
}

const res = connection.on('ready', prompt => {

    connection.exec(cmd, (err, response) => {
        console.log("pront", prompt);
        console.log(response)
        return response;  // **** NEED RETURN THIS RESPONSE
    })
})

console.log("resultado: ", res)

connection.on('timeout', () => {
    console.log('socket timeout!')
    connection.end()
})

connection.on('close', () => {
    console.log('connection closed')
})

connection.connect(params)

return response;
```

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente pude resolver el tema con mi conexión a telnet con node js y telnet-client. Después de mucho investigar, los EventEmitter no retornan valores en sus métodos "on": directamente hay que recargarlos y crear un método que lo devuelva deliberadamente luego de un emmiter. No me pareció cómodo y busqué otras formas.
Luego de analizar me di cuenta que mi problema era un poco más sencillo de resolver: resulta que el cmd que enviaba se ejecutaba antes de hacer login y password en la conexión y esto causaba que siempre se quedara esperando login porque era incorrecto.

La solución que di al tema fue crear un método aparte que ejecutara el comando que necesito unos segundos después de crear la conexión, para esto usé un setTimeout, pero tenía el mismo problema para devolver el resultado en esta función, así que la envolví en una promesa y finalmente pude obtener el resultado de la consola con el resolve de la promesa.

Aquí dejo el código para la posteridad.

```
    async function exceCmd(cmd, conn) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(async () => {
            var res = await conn.exec(cmd);
            console.log("**Repsuesta**", res);
            resolve(res);
        }, 2000);
    });
}

const testTelnet = async function (host) {

    console.log("*** INICIANDO TELNET ***")

    let connection = new Telnet()  //  instancia telnet

    const params = {
        host: host,
        port: 23,
        shellPrompt: '#',
        negotiationMandatory: false,
        loginPrompt: ' login:',
        username: user,
        password: password,
        failedLoginMatch: '/error en autenticacion/',
        timeout: 5000,
    }

    try {
        await connection.connect(params);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(' error # 1', error)
        return;
    }

    const res = await exceCmd(cmd, connection);    

    console.log("**RESPUESTA**: ", res);

    connection.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log("LOG DATA: ", data.toString());
        //hacer el proceso para identificar la falla 
    });

    return res;
}
```